# Где ставить запятую и ставить ли вообще?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Именно поэтому(,) в данной ситуации(,) ученик не может превзойти учителя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые не нужны. Причин для обособления оборота нету.

Comment: На фоне "нету" начало предложения звучит совсем уж высокопарно :)

Comment: Почему, grizzly?)

Comment: Просто мне такое сочетание режет глаз. Если же отвечать формально, то все словари относят "нету" к разговорному стилю, а некоторые даже к сниженному.

Comment: А Микитко говорит, что "нет" произошло от "нету", а не наоборот. Если хотите, исправьте.

Comment: А. Микитко говорит о совсем другом значении "нету" (выражение несогласия), которое теперь стало устаревшим, не так ли? Но в любом случае речь здесь не об этимологии — думаю, многие этимологические прародители перешли со временем в разряд разговорных слов (если не хуже).

Comment: Не А. Микитко, а Микитко сын Алексеев. Вот тут: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTMg9iH7aYs. "Нету" как выражение несогласия — что-то не понимаю... Если б сказали "не-а" как ответ на "Хочешь...?", тогда бы я понял ещё. Кстати, я по поводу другого его видео задал вопрос неделю назад (как к этому относиться, прав ли он). Если есть желание и возможность посмотреть и что-то сказать, буду рад.

Comment: @Артем Луговой, слово "нет" ,действительно, произошло от "нету". Но  литературная норма "нет".

Comment: @Серж: хорошо, Серж, буду иметь в виду. Только зря вы обособили "действительно". Оно же в данном случае не вводное.

Comment: Почему не вводное? У меня как раз вводное. Выражает уверенность говорящего в сообщаемом, употребляется для подтверждения, признания правильности сказанного ранее.

Comment: @Серж: можно его заменить на "на самом деле" у вас. Вводное "действительно" я встречал только в начале предложений в значении "и правда".

Comment: Можно, конечно. Не спорю. Но до этого было утверждение. И слово "действительно" у меня  служит подверждением предыдущей мысли.